# How to create an "Add To Startup" option in the Windows context menu when you right-click a file?

Tags: windows, cmd, registry, contextmenu, startup

I'm trying to add a "Add To Startup" option to my context menu via symlink.

The command works fine when I run it manually. But it doesn't work when I run it from t he context menu.

My command is: `mklink %1 "C:\Startup"`

*C:\Startup is actually a symlink to the original Startup folder.*

I've added it to the context menu via regedit and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Sym To Start\command` but I'm not having any luck.

I've even tried using Powershell to run the command:

```
powershell.exe -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList 'mklink %1 C:\Startup' -Verb runAs"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean [this `mklink` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) (another description at https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: https://www.the-automator.com/add-to-startup/

> Add to Startup is a simple, free, windows tool that adds an option to your context menu.  After installing, simply right-click any file from Windows Explorer and you’ll see the option to “Add to Startup”